How to save Acumatica Stock item Wiki page changes in Visual studio
I have Added Tab in Acumatica Stock item Wiki page.
Now i want to save this changes in my visual studio

i am able to save wiki’s to customization. But i need to save a specific changes. Like we save only our changes we have done in stock item.
But stock item change is save in our visual studio when HelpRoot_FormReference is added in wiki and the file size is above 25MB which large size


You can try using the Source Control-> Save to folder. Then you can add Git or other source control to that folder

@SamvelPetrosov I have already save wiki files but i need to save my changes not acumatica whole file
